# Ag-grid "Size to Fit" on desktop and "Auto-Size" on mobile

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I need ag-grid to be responsive on all devices. When I tried `this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit()` It looks nice on desktop, but in mobile screen column width gets zero
[as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct2Vm.png).

When I give `this.gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds, false);` it leaves a blank space if there are less number of columns [like shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IySsg.jpg).

Is there a way to autoFit in desktop and autoSize in smaller screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call them after another. I'd suggest to first call the `autoSizeColumns`.

Afterwards you calculate the actual tableWidth with something like

```js
const tableWidth = grid.columnApi.getAllColumns()
    .reduce((i, current) => i += current.getActualWidth(), 0);
```

and then you calculate the actual container width

```js
const {left, right} = grid.api.getHorizontalPixelRange();
const containerWidth = right - left;
```

and only if the tableWidth is smaller than the container width you call `sizeColumnsToFit``

```js
if (tableWidth < containerWidth) {
     grid.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
}
```